# Listener stops immediately after starting

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle11g, opensuse

Please suggest the change in configuration required to prevent listner from stopping immediately after starting.

```
oracle@linux-0nrm:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1> lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 25-JAN-2014 01:10:30

Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle. All rights reserved.

Starting /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
System parameter file is /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/linux-0nrm/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=linux-0nrm.site)(PORT=1521)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=extproc)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=linux-0nrm.site)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias LISTENER
Version TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date 25-JAN-2014 01:10:32
Uptime 0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level off
Security ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP OFF
Listener Parameter File /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/linux-0nrm/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=linux-0nrm.site)(PORT=1521)))
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=extproc)))
Services Summary...
Service "newdb" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "newdb", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully

oracle@linux-0nrm:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1> lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 25-JAN-2014 01:10:44

Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle. All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=linux-0nrm.site)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
TNS-00511: No listener
Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=extproc)(queuesize=50)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
TNS-00511: No listener
Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
```

Output of `gen|env`:

```
LESSKEY=/etc/lesskey.bin
XDG_VTNR=7
NNTPSERVER=news
MANPATH=/usr/lib/mpi/gcc/openmpi/share/man:/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man
XDG_SESSION_ID=2
HOSTNAME=linux-0nrm.site
ORA_CRS_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/10gR2/crs
XKEYSYMDB=/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/XKeysymDB
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/oracle/keyring-rKwoSL/gpg:0:1
SHELL=/bin/bash
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-
HOST=linux-0nrm.site
TERM=xterm
HISTSIZE=1000
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE=aaf45848b77796875f161bed0000071b-1390590701.757075-721617866
PROFILEREAD=true
TMPDIR=/tmp
ORACLE_UNQNAME=DB11G
GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT=stderr
MORE=-sl
WINDOWID=44040197
OLDPWD=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/run/user/oracle/keyring-rKwoSL
XSESSION_IS_UP=yes
GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS=JS ERROR;JS LOG
ORA_ASM_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/10gR2/asm
GTK_MODULES=canberra-gtk-module
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre
USER=oracle
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
LS_COLORS=no=00:fi=00:di=01;34:ln=00;36:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=41;33;01:ex=00;32:*.cmd=00;32:*.exe=01; 32:*.com=01;32:*.bat=01;32:*.btm=01;32:*.dll=01;32:*.tar=00;31:*.tbz=00;31:*.tgz=00;31:*.rpm=00;31:*.deb=00;31:*.arj=00;31:*.taz=00;3 1:*.lzh=00;31:*.lzma=00;31:*.zip=00;31:*.zoo=00;31:*.z=00;31:*.Z=00;31:*.gz=00;31:*.bz2=00;31:*.tb2=00;31:*.tz2=00;31:*.tbz2=00;31:*. xz=00;31:*.avi=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.p bm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.aiff =00;32:*.au=00;32:*.mid=00;32:*.mp3=00;32:*.ogg=00;32:*.voc=00;32:*.wav=00;32:
ORACLE_SID=newdb
XNLSPATH=/usr/share/X11/nls
HOSTTYPE=i386
ORACLE_HOSTNAME=127.0.0.1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/oracle/keyring-rKwoSL/ssh
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
CONFIG_SITE=/usr/share/site/i686-pc-linux-gnu
SESSION_MANAGER=local/linux-0nrm.site:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1105,unix/linux-0nrm.site:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1105
USERNAME=oracle
FROM_HEADER=
PAGER=less
COLUMNS=140
CSHEDIT=emacs
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg
MINICOM=-c on
PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin:/usr/sbin:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0 /dbhome_1/bin:/usr/lib/mpi/gcc/openmpi/bin:/home/oracle/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/usr/ lib/mit/bin:/opt/oracle/product/10gR2/db/bin
TNS_ADMIN=/opt/oracle/product/10gR2/db/network/admin
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/oracle
DESKTOP_SESSION=gnome
CPU=i686
QT_IM_MODULE=xim
PWD=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
INPUTRC=/home/oracle/.inputrc
XMODIFIERS=@im=local
LANG=en_US.utf8
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=1086
PYTHONSTARTUP=/etc/pythonstart
GDM_LANG=en_US.utf8
AGENT_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/10.2/agent
LINES=39
GDMSESSION=gnome
GPG_TTY=/dev/pts/0
ICEAUTHORITY=/home/oracle/.ICEauthority
XDG_SEAT=seat0
QT_SYSTEM_DIR=/usr/share/desktop-data
HOME=/home/oracle
SHLVL=2
OSTYPE=linux
SDL_AUDIODRIVER=pulse
ALSA_CONFIG_PATH=/etc/alsa-pulse.conf
LESS_ADVANCED_PREPROCESSOR=no
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
XCURSOR_THEME=DMZ
LS_OPTIONS=-N --color=tty -T 0
WINDOWMANAGER=/usr/bin/gnome
LOGNAME=oracle
MACHTYPE=i686-suse-linux
TMP=/tmp
LESS=-M -I -R
G_FILENAME_ENCODING=@locale,UTF-8,ISO-8859-15,CP1252
CVS_RSH=ssh
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-z2EOIPsCwM,guid=31f2ca8d8a705468a53cc1340000004a
CLASSPATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/jlib:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/jlib
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share
LESSOPEN=lessopen.sh %s
WINDOWPATH=7
DISPLAY=:0
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/oracle
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
GTK_IM_MODULE=cedilla
XAUTHLOCALHOSTNAME=localhost
LESSCLOSE=lessclose.sh %s %s
QT_IM_SWITCHER=imsw-multi
G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1
COLORTERM=gnome-terminal
XAUTHORITY=/home/oracle/.xauth3QPCtf
JAVA_ROOT=/usr/lib/jvm/jre
_=/usr/bin/env
```

The output of log file `/u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/linux-0nrm/listener/trace/listner.log`:

```
Sun Jan 26 04:26:39 2014
System parameter file is /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/linux-0nrm/listener/alert/log.xml
Trace information written to /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/linux-0nrm/listener/trace/ora_2952_3042879168.trc
Trace level is currently 0

Started with pid=2952
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=linux-0nrm.site)(PORT=1521)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=extproc)))
Listener completed notification to CRS on start

TIMESTAMP * CONNECT DATA [* PROTOCOL INFO] * EVENT [* SID] * RETURN CODE
WARNING: Subscription for node down event still pending
26-JAN-2014 04:26:39 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=linux-0nrm.site)(USER=oracle))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=LISTENER)(VERSION=186646784)) * status * 0
```

`ps -ef|grep lsnr` doesn't show a listener, and `netstat` doesn't show port 1521 as listening.

################log.xml

**output of /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/linux-0nrm/listener/alert/log.xml**

```
<msg time='2014-01-26T04:26:39.865+05:30' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='linux-0nrm.site'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
 <txt>System parameter file is /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2014-01-26T04:26:39.866+05:30' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='linux-0nrm.site'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
 <txt>Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/linux-0nrm/listener/alert/log.xml
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2014-01-26T04:26:39.866+05:30' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='linux-0nrm.site'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
 <txt>Trace information written to /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/linux-0nrm/listener/trace/ora_2952_3042879168.trc
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2014-01-26T04:26:39.866+05:30' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='linux-0nrm.site'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
 <txt>Trace level is currently 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2014-01-26T04:26:39.866+05:30' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='linux-0nrm.site'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
 <txt>
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2014-01-26T04:26:39.867+05:30' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='linux-0nrm.site'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
 <txt>Started with pid=2952
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2014-01-26T04:26:39.869+05:30' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='linux-0nrm.site'
<msg time='2014-01-26T04:26:39.865+05:30' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='linux-0nrm.site'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
 <txt>System parameter file is /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2014-01-26T04:26:39.866+05:30' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='linux-0nrm.site'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
 <txt>Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/linux-0nrm/listener/alert/log.xml
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2014-01-26T04:26:39.866+05:30' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='linux-0nrm.site'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
 <txt>Trace information written to /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/linux-0nrm/listener/trace/ora_2952_3042879168.trc
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2014-01-26T04:26:39.866+05:30' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='linux-0nrm.site'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
 <txt>Trace level is currently 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2014-01-26T04:26:39.866+05:30' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='linux-0nrm.site'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
 <txt>
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2014-01-26T04:26:39.867+05:30' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='linux-0nrm.site'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
 <txt>Started with pid=2952
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2014-01-26T04:26:39.869+05:30' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='linux-0nrm.site'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
 <txt>Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=linux-0nrm.site)(PORT=1521)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2014-01-26T04:26:39.869+05:30' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='linux-0nrm.site'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
 <txt>Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=extproc)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2014-01-26T04:26:39.873+05:30' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='linux-0nrm.site'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
 <txt>Listener completed notification to CRS on start
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2014-01-26T04:26:39.873+05:30' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='linux-0nrm.site'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
 <txt>

TIMESTAMP * CONNECT DATA [* PROTOCOL INFO] * EVENT [* SID] * RETURN CODE
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2014-01-26T04:26:39.876+05:30' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='linux-0nrm.site'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
 <txt>WARNING: Subscription for node down event still pending
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2014-01-26T04:26:39.876+05:30' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='linux-0nrm.site'
 host_addr='127.0.0.1'>
 <txt>26-JAN-2014 04:26:39 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=linux-0nrm.site)(USER=oracle))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=LISTENER)(VERSION=186646784)) * status * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
```

**I didn't find u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/linux-0nrm/listener/trace/ora_2952_3042879168.t‌​rc
trace file instead in trace folder listner.log file was present output of which i have already shared.**

**CONTENT LISTNER.ORA FILE**

```
 listener.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

#LISTENER1 =
#  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
#    (DESCRIPTION =
#      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = linux-0nrm.site)(PORT = 1521))
#    )
# )

#ADR_BASE_LISTENER1 = /u01/app/oracle/

#LISTENER =
#  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
#    (DESCRIPTION =
#      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = linux-0nrm.site)(PORT = 1521))
#    )
#  )

#ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /u01/app/oracle

LISTENER=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS_LIST=
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=linux-0nrm.site)(PORT=1521))
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=extproc) (queuesize=50))))
#ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /u01/app/oracle

SID_LIST_listener=
(SID_LIST=
 (SID_DESC=
  (GLOBAL_DBNAME=newdb)
  (SID_NAME=newdb)
  (ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1)))
```

**however portlist.ini file has following content**

```
PATH : /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/install/portlist.ini

Enterprise Manager Console HTTP Port (newdb) = 1158
Enterprise Manager Agent Port (newdb) = 3938
```

**Will installing oracle 11g again help? and any link to process of installation of oracle 11g for open suse, please do suggest.**

Comment: What does the listener log file have to say?

Comment: What about the alert log `/u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/linux-0nrm/listener/alert/log.xml, and the trace file`u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/linux-0nrm/listener/trace/ora_2952_3042879168.trc`? We can't guess what it's doing but the logs should tell you. Since it's up briefly I'd wonder if something is explicitly shutting it down.

Comment: Can you also include the listener.ora file?  I've seen those lsnrctl error messages before when the listener uses a non-standard name and current_listener is not set.  (Although I would still expect `ps` to show something.)

Comment: @jonearles - the startup says `Alias LISTENER` so I'd kind of ruled that out; but it would probably still be useful. Is there anything in there that could make it start, register the DBs, and then stop? Seems like it must either be crashing, or another session is shutting it down for some reason, which would be odd...